# Low-level light detection

Tags: sensor, light

I'm looking for the best way to detect a weak bluish light (440nm) in a dark environment - with "best" I mean with highest sensitivity possible. I've noticed that most LDRs and photodiodes have their peak wavelength around 550~600 nm, and phototransistors at that range also include UV, driving up their prices.

So what would be the most efficient way? Using a LED to filter to the blue bandwidth, buy a more expensive UV+Blue phototransistor, rely on a IC like a light-to-frequency converter, or does it all depend on the measuring circuit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably a [PMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomultiplier) (Photo Multiplier Tube), if you really need "the highest sensitivity possible".

Here's the response of one commercial [module](http://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=2909).

[image]

Somewhat less effective, would be a blue-enhanced avalanche [photodiode](http://www.first-sensor.com/en/products/components/detectors/avalanche-photodiodes-apd).

Comment: It should be notes that "highest sensitivity" in this context means *single photon detection*. Photomultipliers can resolve single photons. I'd *strongly* suggest that they're *massively* overkill for what the OP wants, but considering the poor specificity of the OP's question, it's a completely valid answer.

Comment: It's not an insane solution if the OP needs just one- they're available on eBay for tens of dollars, probably a similar amount to a specialized blue-sensitive photodiode.

Comment: They're not so simple to use. You need a high-voltage supply to make them work at all, generally in the range of several kilovolts. They're not easy to power.

Comment: @ConnorWolf True, but that's just another interesting electronics project, and you can get the dynode power supplies surplus too.